# Android: extra security for strings by encryption

Tags: android, string, encryption, google-play, apk

I would make my Android app show a toast to remind the user to upgrade to premium version.

I would like to know whether it does make sense to conjure the message by decrypting a resource text file with secret strings so it cannot be pirated.

I mean: if the message string in the strings.xml is replaced in the apk with an empty string by a pirate (who wants to distribute the apk on a website) the user can use the app without being bothered so never purchases it.

Comment: What kind of feature do you want to protect?

Comment: No, you cannot hide or lock away anything in your apk. The code, the resources, everything. As soon as you push the publish button your app is essentially open source.

Comment: @jonas.koeritz I want that the toast is not empty if the string is changed by a pirate in the apk

Answer (score 0):

If you place these strings within your apk, it will **never** be secure enough.
The better option here is to use a backend API to retrieve these strings resources. This way, if you're need to use some of its functions. It have to contact your backend API first to retrieve these resources.

Comment: I think the app can perform some check about the encryption and give at least an error, am I wrong?

Comment: That is one of the most terrible ideas I have ever heard. Don't listen to this answer. Retrieving translations from a server is insane.

Comment: @XaverKapeller any better idea to help with such requirement? I did not mean to save the whole strings for app in backend, we only need to keep the necessary/sensitive ones, like message and address to help user update/purchase.